# Find the roots (real or complex) of the equation $2a^2(1+\cos x) - (1+a^2 +b^2)^2 = 0$, $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, roots, inverse-function

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the equation 
$$
2a^2(1+\cos x) - (1+a^2 + b^2)^2 = 0\text{.}
$$
The problem is to find all possible solutions $x \in \mathbb{C}$ (set of complex numbers) that satisfy the above equality for a given real numbers $a$ and $b$.

**ATTEMPT:** Solving for $x$, we arrived with
$$
x = \arccos \Bigg[ \frac{(1+a^2 + b^2)^2}{2a^2}-1\Bigg]\text{.}
$$
However, I got stuck because of the required domain of $\arccos(\cdot)$ which is $[-1,1]$ while the  expression $\frac{(1+a^2 + b^2)^2}{2a^2}-1$ does not possibly be within this interval for arbitrary values of $a$ and $b$. Sometimes I am tempted to say that *no general solution exists even in $\mathbb{C}$*. Can anyone help me out?

**EDIT:** What I actually want is a simple detailed derivation for $x$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ which possibly be in complex form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should know is $\arccos x$, if the domain is $[-1,1]$, it has real value, and if the domain isn't, then it has **complex** value.

Take a look: we calculate the value of $\cos i$, so using Euler formula:

$$\cos i=\dfrac{e^{ii}+e^{-ii}}{2}=\dfrac{e+e^{-1}}{2}$$

The answer is larger than $1$.

So if your problem is solved in $\mathbb{C}$, then there is no problem when the value inside $\arccos$ is not in the range $[-1,1]$.

Side note: You have solved your problem.

Comment: Yes I know that $x$ possibly is complex. But what I want is an explicit form of $x$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. Can you help me out with this in terms of a more detailed derivation?

Comment: I think I got it now. I just need stipulate that $\arccos$ is defined on  $\mathbb{C}$.
By noting that for a complex $z = x+iy$, when considering only the principal value, the 
$$
\arccos z = \frac{1}{i}\text{Ln}(z  + i \sqrt{1-z^2})
$$
where $\text{Ln}(z)$ is principal logarithm of $z$ defined as 
$$
\text{Ln}(z) = \ln|z| + i\text{Arg} z.
$$

Comment: Since the range of $\cosh x$ is just disjoint with $\cos x$, using relation $$\cos x=\cosh ix$$ will be fine, if you want to find $\cos^{-1}2$, solve what value of complex $x$ makes $\cosh ix=2$, that is $x=i\ln(2\pm\sqrt3)$, so we can say $$\cos^{-1}2=i\ln(2\pm\sqrt3)$$
you can discover more by using $\cosh $ function.